# rails passing a local variable to a partial got some errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'am trying to pass a local variable to a partial, but I got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `blubb' for #<#<Class:0x00000007cb8c00>:0x00000007c79f78>
```

My code looks like this:

```
 <% rate = Rating.where(["comment_id = ? and movie_id = ?", comment.id, @movie.id]) %>

  <% @ratingvalue = rate[0][:ratingvalue] %>

 <div class="col-md-3 text-right"><%= render :partial => "shared/starRating", :locals => {blubb: @ratingvalue} %> </div>
```

When I inspect @ratingvalue there is my integer value inside.

Then in the partial I try to do this:

```
<%= blubb %>
```

but then I got the error.

also tried this:

```
<%= :blubb %>
```

but then only blubb is printed ...

What is going wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: make the variable ratingvalue a instance variable in viewer does not make sense.

Comment: [Have a look](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) at the way you can render partials in rails 4

Comment: The code looks fine, except for the old style notation - could you post the partial code itself in case there is something missing from the context?

Comment: in partial is only this: <%= blubb %>

Comment: @Felix - Hmm, your code is perfectly working for me. Can you post all your views file code (maybe you forget something, or you have 2 partial views...)? Because I tested your code on Rails 4.2.4 and everything working well

Comment: which files do you want? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code look fine, Btw you can try this:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/starRating", :object => @ratingvalue %>
```

and in the partial you can using `@ratingvalue` variable.